# evalute $\int \frac{1}{x^6+x^4+7x^3+7x}\mathrm{ d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to evalute this integral $$\int \frac{1}{x^6+x^4+7x^3+7x}\mathrm{ d}x$$

Comment: Why down votes ?

Comment: You did not show what you have a problem with. At least the factorization of the denominator polynomial should be easy enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$x^6+x^4+7x^3+7x=x\{(x^2+1)x^3+7(x^2+1)\}=x(x^2+1)(x^3+7)$$

Start with partial fraction decomposition:

$$\dfrac1{x^6+x^4+7x^3+7x}=\dfrac Ax+\dfrac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{Dx^2+Ex+F}{x^3+7}$$

Comment: One could get one step further with $x^3+7=(x+\sqrt[3]7)(x^2-\sqrt[3]7x+\sqrt[3]7^2)$.